# Fill in small cracks in my wood cutting board

Tags: wood, adhesive, board

I would like to fill in small cracks in my wood cutting boards.

The cracks are the ones seen from the pieces being attached to each other.

I would like to fill those cracks with a non-toxic wood glue.

Elmer's Carpenters Wood Glue says it is water soluble and non-toxic.

Would it be safe to use?

Nontoxic

Comment: A fast google search says most glues are not food grade, able to touch food.  Some are food safe where the food does not touch them.  Shellac is food grade, so might use the glue then shellac on top.  Nontoxic means mainly it won't kill you if eaten, might make you sick.

Comment: You have the answer. I hit the up arrow on your comment What do I do next? @crip659

Comment: It depends on you.  Most food safe and food grade labels are for public food preparation.  For a person, the tiny bit of stuff the food might pick up, might not matter.  Google searches seem to recommend one brand/make of wood glue over the others for wood cutting boards, but unknown if just paid product placement.

Comment: From a safety/hygiene perspective, you should discard any cutting board with nicks or cracks. They harbour bacteria & spores & cannot be properly cleaned. This is even worse for a butcher's block type that cannot go in the dishwasher. Time for a new board. See https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/32863/42066

Comment: @Tetsujin From my experience, they can be properly cleaned.

Comment: Does your experience include years of research into food-borne contaminants, bacteria & toxins?

Comment: All adhesives are food safe _once they have fully cured_. The only possible exception to that is if some of it were to detach from the cutting board and be ingested with the food. However, general PVA glue (of which the Elmer's in question is one), isn't really the right solution for filling gaps. Generally, epoxy would be used for this. However, a picture of the gaps in question would probably help. I also recommend a tour of [woodworking.se] to get more information on cutting boards - there is even a [tag:cutting-board] tag there to peruse.

Answer (score 2):

This is most likely caused by the wood getting too wet. The boards have warped and the glue wasn’t strong enough to prevent it. If this is a cutting board worth the effort, I would cut it apart at the split and get each side straight enough to reglue. Titebond  3 is a waterproof glue. Epoxy also, but much messier to work with.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I  would throw it away and buy a new one from the "two dollar store" or its equivalent.

In its manufacture, the pieces would have been glued and squeezed together,  which would have removed excess glue.

Anything you do as a filler will get cut by the knife and enter your food.  As mentioned, most glues will be toxic if ingested. As a filler, more of it can get into your food.

The purpose of a wood chopping board is to use a natural product. The theory is that the bugs living in the microscopic cracks are supposed to be beneficial. Large cracks are probably not good. But I  wouldn't pollute it with artificial glue.

Here's another opinion from [9 Do’s & Don’ts Of Caring For Wooden Cutting Boards & Utensils](https://www.ruralsprout.com/wooden-cutting-board-care/)

> Wooden cutting boards and utensils that develop cracks should be thrown away.

Results of wood glue testing (exposed to Air not in a **Seam**)

> While listening to the healthy home podcast called ‘Non-Toxic Environments’, I learned that wood glues, which are advertised as ‘non-toxic,’ may be, in fact, very toxic.  Particularly the ‘less-toxic’ water-based wood glues!
>
> Glue Area Exposed to Air (Formaldehyde test)
>
> Titebond Original Glue – 0 ppb
> Titebond II Glue – 99 ppb
> Titebond III Glue – 50 ppb
> Titebond Hide Glue – 0 ppb

From [‘Non-Toxic’ Water-Based Wood Glues, are Indeed Toxic – off gassing formaldehyde](https://impressionsofaholobiont.com/2018/09/03/non-toxic-water-based-wood-glues-are-indeed-toxic-off-gassing-formaldehyde/)

> **So, What Kind Of Glue Is Food Safe Enough For Direct Food Contact?**
> Honestly? None of them. Or at least, there is no durable long-lasting glue made from wholly food grade ingredients. And a glue thats strong enough to build a chopping block, will inevitably contain strong inedible chemical additives.
>
> In fact, take a good look at the labels of food-safe wood glues. All of them will make mention of the fact that they are FDA food safe for ‘indirect contact with food’.
>
> The key word here is ‘indirect’.

From [What Food Grade Wood Glue Is Safe Enough For Your Cutting Board?](https://www.thewoodworkplace.com/what-glue-is-safe-for-cutting-boards/)

Comment: "most glues will be toxic if ingested." do you have support for this? Most dried and cured glues are not toxic AFAIK, but don't make them part of your meal of course ;)

Comment: This group is the most critical group of all the MANY stack exchange groups that I participate in. Most participants, but NOT all are not helpful. In other groups, my points are 4 times what I have gotten here. It is really sad because I see so much potential.

Comment: @P2000 - I have updated my answer.  The thing to note is that as a filler, it's in direct contact with food.  What you are referring to is when it's applied in a seam.  I was very familiar with P2000C, is the P2000T similar ?

Comment: ha ha ha @RohitGupta it was indeed a P2000T in High School, my first Z80 assembly experience. No different animal: colour TV was your monitor, with "teletext" graphics (6 pixel cursor block) BTW thank you for the updates. I find references make these opinion questions and answers a lot better for an informative site like this one.

Comment: @fixit7 I think Rohit did a nice job of adding support for the information provided. You can discuss your opinions of the site on https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com